# mapply for better performance

Tags: r, performance, matrix, mapply

I want to apply a function to a matrix input `a`, this function would change the first element to `c[a[1]]` and the next elements to `b[a[i],a[i+1]]` starting from `i = 1` up to `i = ncol(a) - 1`.

**example input:**

```
a <- matrix(c(1,4,3,1),nrow=1)
b <- matrix(1:25,ncol=5,nrow=5)
c <- matrix(4:8,ncol=5,nrow=1)
```

**expected output:**

```
>a
4 16 14 3

#c[a[1]] gave us the first element: 4
#b[a[1],a[2]] gave us the second element: 16 
#b[a[2],a[3]] gave us the third element: 14
#b[a[3],a[4]] gave us the fourth element: 3
```

I've been trying to use `mapply()` without any success so far. The idea is to avoid loops since those things can lead to major performance decrease in R

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Step 1: using single index for addressing matrix**

In R matrix elements are stored in column-major order into a vector, so `A[i, j]` is the same as `A[(j-1)*nrow(A) + i]`. Consider an example of random 3-by-3 matrix:

```
set.seed(1); A <- round(matrix(runif(9), 3, 3), 2)

> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,] 0.27 0.91 0.94
[2,] 0.37 0.20 0.66
[3,] 0.57 0.90 0.63
```

Now, this matrix has 3 rows (`nrow(A) = 3`). Compare:

```
A[2,3]  # 0.66
A[(3-1) * 3 + 2]  # 0.66
```

**Step 2: vectorizing**

You can address multiple elements of a matrix at a time. **However, you can only do this by using single indexing mode (Not too precise here, see @alexis_laz's remark later)**. For example, if you want to extract `A[1,2]` and `A[3,1]`, but if you do:

```
A[c(1,3), c(2,1)]
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] 0.91 0.27
# [2,] 0.90 0.57
```

You actually get a block. Now, if you use single indexing, you get what you need:

```
A[3 * (c(2,1) - 1) + c(1,3)]
# [1] 0.91 0.57
```

**Step 3: getting single index for your problem**

Suppose `n <- length(a)` and you want to address those elements of `b`:

```
a[1]    a[2]
a[2]    a[3]
 .       .
 .       .
a[n-1]  a[n]
```

you can use single index `nrow(b) * (a[2:n] - 1) + a[1:(n-1)]`.

**Step 4: complete solution**

Since you only have single row for `a` and `c`, you should store them as vectors rather than matrices.

```
a <- c(1,4,3,1)
c <- 4:8
```

If you were given a matrix and have no choice (as they are currently are in your question), you can convert them into vectors by:

```
a <- as.numeric(a)
c <- as.numeric(c)
```

Now, as discussed, we have index for address `b` matrix:

```
n <- length(a)
b_ind <- nrow(b) * (a[2:n] - 1) + a[1:(n-1)]
```

You also address `a[1]` element of `c` as the first element of your final result, so we need concatenate: `c[a[1]]` and `b[b_ind]` by:

```
a <- c(c[a[1]], b[b_ind])
# > a
# [1]  4 16 14  3
```

This approach is fully vectorized, even better than `*apply` family.

---

**alexis_laz's remark**

alexis_laz reminds me that we can use "matrix-index" as well, i.e., we can also address matrix `b` via:

```
b[cbind(a[1:(n-1)],a[2:n])]  ## or b[cbind(a[-n], a[-1])]
```

However, I think using single index is slightly faster, because we need to access the index matrix by row in order to address `b`, so we pay higher memory latency than using vector index.